# What does $4^{\frac{1}{2}}$ equal? +2 or -2 or both?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

What does $$4^{\frac{1}{2}}$$ equal?
   +2 or -2 or both?

Is there an implication that it's only equal to the (+) square root ?

Comment: Actually, $4^{1/2}$ is unambiguously equal to $2.$ If you want the negative square root, you'd have to write $-4^{1/2}.$

Comment: It is certainly neither $4$ nor $-4$

Comment: How long does it take that you notice that  $\pm 4$ doesn´t make any sense? 20 minutes have passed.

Comment: I don't know people are discussing about what! in precalculus we have just $4^\frac12=2$.

Comment: Why doesn't +/-2 make sense?   sqrt of 4 is both +/-2.   "What number multiplies by itself to get 4?"   The answer to that is +2 and -2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The roots of $x^2=4$ are $+2$ and $-2$. The real root *functions* (or root operations if you want) are defined to have positive values for positive arguments.

Answer (score 2):

The usual convention  is that $a^{m/n}$ for $a > 0$ is the positive $n$'th root of $a^m$.  However, when you get to complex variables, non-integer powers become multivalued functions
and all roots must be considered.

Comment: "and all roots must be considered." Unless otherwise specified, I would still interpret $z^{1/2}$ as single valued by taking a principle branch. I rarely see anyone arguing for $(-1)^{1/2}=-i$.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Much as I like the principal branch, it is not always the best choice.  But this is probably not the place for such discussions.

Answer (score 0):

In general

> $$a^{1/b}=\sqrt[b]{a}\implies 4^{1/2}=\sqrt[2]{4}=2$$

If you want $-2$ to be the result, you'd have to write $-4^{1/2}$

Comment: Why the downvote?